# geocoder location lookup

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using this nice rails gem: https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder

A user enters in their location say "San Francisco".  This gets stored in the place object attribute.  Geocoder then fetches the coordinates and then with the coordinates gets the full address.

Model:

```
geocoded_by :place
after_validation :fetch_coordinates
after_validation :set_label

reverse_geocoded_by :latitude, :longitude
after_validation :fetch_address
```

This all works fine.  But I would like to customize the final format.  If someone enters "San Francisco", geocoder then puts in: "1601-1645 Market St, San Francisco, CA 94103, USA" to the address.  How can I modify this to save as San Francisco, CA, USA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll have to first caveat my answer with I am not using this gem.  In looking at the documentation, it looks like you can get what you want by passing a block to reverse_geocoded_by:

```
reverse_geocoded_by :lat, :lon do |obj,geo|
  obj.city    = geo.city
  obj.zipcode = geo.postal_code
  obj.country = geo.country_code
end
after_validation :reverse_geocode
```

There is more info in the Advanced Geocoding section.

With your code snippet I'm guessing you want something similar to:

```
reverse_geocoded_by :latitude, :longitude do |obj,geo|
  obj.address  = [geo.city, geo.state, geo.country_code].join(",")
end
after_validation :reverse_geocode
```

I do think the availability of city/state/country is based on the geocoder you have configured the gem to use.  You can look in https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder/tree/master/lib/geocoder/results to see what gets populated for each geocoder.